# CSS: Right column not under the menu bar anymore

Tags: html, css, templates, blogger

I am working on the layout of a [blog](http://www.aboutefficiency.com/), and the layout is now broken:

[image]

The right column is now sliding under the menu and I don't know what is causing this layout issue. I can't spot the trouble in the code. The page is generated out of a blogger template. It contains its own CSS.

Anyone sees the problem? The layout used to work fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed two extra `</div>` in the code, but could not figure why these were generated. I had to restart the template modifications from scratch to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer is the headers wrap (.bloginner-wrapper) is set to 'z-index:999'. Everything shouldnt be in wrapped divs, float your sidebar and content inside one responsive wrap.